# Does Spark streaming receivers continue pulling data for every block interval during the current micro-batch

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

For every **spark.streaming.blockInterval** (say, 1 minute) receivers listen to streaming sources for data. Suppose the current micro-batch is taking an unnaturally long time to complete (by intention, say 20 min). During this micro-batch, would the Receivers still listens to the streaming source and store it in Spark memory?

The current pipeline runs in Azure Databricks by using Spark Structured Streaming.
Can anyone help me understand this!

Answer (score 0):

With the above scenario the Spark will continue to consume/pull data from Kafka and micro batches will continue to pile up and eventually cause Out of memory (OOM) issues.
In order to avoid the scenario enable back pressure setting,

> spark.streaming.backpressure.enabled=true

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html

For more details on Spark back pressure feature

Comment: Thank you Quicksilver for the clarification. One follow up. For understanding, Is there any way to see how much the receivers have consumed in terms of spark memory for backlogging queues?

Comment: Yes you can see the Driver and executor memory usage along with batch processing delay metrics via inbuilt Spark metric sinks. Please follow below URL,
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html